# Добавить в многомерный массив сгрупированные данные из другого массива

Tags: php, массивы, циклы

Помогите пожалуйста.

**Есть массив 1:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cnt] => 4 //общая сумма просмотров всех видео на странице подсчитанных из массива 2
            [id_page] => 363 //страница на которой было просмотрено всего "cnt"-4 видео
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [cnt] => 3
            [id_page] => 102
        )
)
```

**Есть массив 2:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1 // порядковый номер
            [data_click] => 1535215098 // время когда было просмотрено видео
            [id_video] => 563 //ID просмотренного видео
            [id_page] => 363 //Страница на которой было просмотрено видео
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [data_click] => 1535215549
            [id_video] => 564
            [id_page] => 363
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [data_click] => 1535215935
            [id_video] => 563
            [id_page] => 363
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [data_click] => 1535216040
            [id_video] => 563
            [id_page] => 363
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [data_click] => 1535743017
            [id_video] => 564
            [id_page] => 103
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [data_click] => 1535743024
            [id_video] => 564
            [id_page] => 103
        )
    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [data_click] => 1535743113
            [id_video] => 563
            [id_page] => 103
        )
```

Как мне сделать массив 3, что бы в нем были сгрупированные данные из этих двух массивов? На выходе должно получится так:
**Массив 3:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cnt] => 4 // Сумма всех просмотренных видео на странице
            [id_page] => 363 // Страница на которой были просмотрены видео
            [more_video] => Array //Массив где просмотры разбиваем по каждому видео
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id_video] => 563 //ID видео
                            [show_video] => 2 // Кол-во просмотров этого видео на странице с ID 363
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id_video] => 564
                            [show_video] => 2
                        )
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [cnt] => 3
            [id_page] => 103
            [more_video] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id_video] => 563
                            [show_video] => 2
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id_video] => 564
                            [show_video] => 1
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: А где значение `show_video` в изначальных данных? Я не наблюдаю его, и объясните конкретнее как вы хотите сделать это.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ: 1 массив "cnt" - это сумма просмотров видео "id_video" на каждой странице "id_page" из 2го массива. А "show_video" - это сумма просмотров конкретного видео "id_video" на данной странице "id_page"

Comment: Добавил комментарии в описании еще, на всякий случай,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изначально имеем 2 массива:

```
$arr1 = [
    ['cnt' => 4, 'id_page' => 363],
    ['cnt' => 3, 'id_page' => 103]
];

$arr2 = [
    ['id' => 1, 'data_click' => 1535215098, 'id_video' => 563, 'id_page' => 363],
    ['id' => 2, 'data_click' => 1535215549, 'id_video' => 564, 'id_page' => 363],
    ['id' => 3, 'data_click' => 1535215935, 'id_video' => 563, 'id_page' => 363],
    ['id' => 4, 'data_click' => 1535216040, 'id_video' => 563, 'id_page' => 363],
    ['id' => 5, 'data_click' => 1535743017, 'id_video' => 564, 'id_page' => 103],
    ['id' => 6, 'data_click' => 1535743024, 'id_video' => 564, 'id_page' => 103],
    ['id' => 7, 'data_click' => 1535743113, 'id_video' => 563, 'id_page' => 103],
];
```

Далее проводим нужные преобразования:

```
foreach ($arr1 as $page)
{
    foreach ($arr2 as $click)
    {
        if ($click['id_page'] === $page['id_page'])
        {
            if (!isset($tmp[$click['id_video']])) {
                $tmp[$click['id_video']] = 0;
            }

            $tmp[$click['id_video']]++;
        }
    }

    $more_video = [];

    foreach ($tmp as $id => $count) {
        $more_video[] = [
            'id_video' => $id,
            'show_video' => $count,
        ];
    }

    $page['more_video'] = $more_video;
    $result[] = $page;
}
```

Comment: Для первой итерации отрабатывает идеально, а со второй начинает копировать и дополнять данные из предыдущих итераций

Comment: @KostasGrek, исправил